# Keyboard combinations in Elm 0.17 and later

Tags: elm

How do I build keyboard combinations into my Elm app, eg. "shift + alt + enter"? You would do something like this to react to a single key pressed (for example the enter key):

```
import Keyboard

type Msg
  = KeyDown Keyboard.KeyCode

type alias Model =
  ...

update msg model =
    case msg of
        KeyDown key ->
          handleKeyDown key model

subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ 
          Keyboard.downs KeyDown
        ]

handleKeyDown key model =
  case key of
    13 -> -- Enter key
      Debug.log "Other key"
      model

    _ -> -- Any other key
      Debug.log "Other key"
      model


view model =
    ...
```

But how can you do the same for multiple keys pressed?

Comment: Have you considered maintaining a list of down keys using [`Keyboard.downs` and `Keyboard.ups`](https://github.com/elm-lang/keyboard/blob/master/src/Keyboard.elm)? I'd create a sample app for you, but I haven't yet come to terms with the breaking changes in 0.17.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Yes I actually did, and I'm kind of afraid of eventually having resort to do that, I just think it feels kind of wrong to "tax" the system on every keypress in apps that are writing intensive and will recieve alot of keypresses. Like "find key in list and delete it" on EVERY keyup? I must however say I don't know very much about how efficient this kind of stuff is, maybe it's peanuts.

Comment: I think your concern is valid, I'm just not aware of an alternative approach using the available APIs. Though, just to follow up on my initial suggestion, you'd probably want to use a set instead of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Keyboard.downs` as pdoherty926 mentioned as well as a `Set` to keep track of which keys are pressed. You'll need to look at `Keyboard.ups` as well to know when a key is released.

Here is a working example:

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App exposing (program)
import Keyboard exposing (..)
import Set exposing (Set)
import Char

main =
  program { init = (initialModel, Cmd.none), view = view, update = update, subscriptions = subscriptions }

initialModel =
  { keysDown = Set.empty
  }

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  text <| toString <| Set.map Char.fromCode model.keysDown

type Msg
  = KeyDown KeyCode
  | KeyUp KeyCode

type alias Model =
  { keysDown : Set KeyCode
  }

update msg model =
  case msg of
    KeyDown key ->
      ({ model | keysDown = Set.insert key model.keysDown }, Cmd.none)
    KeyUp key ->
      ({ model | keysDown = Set.remove key model.keysDown }, Cmd.none)

subscriptions _ =
    Sub.batch
        [ Keyboard.downs KeyDown
        , Keyboard.ups KeyUp
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you think there could be any performance issues from tracking and doing stuff on every keyup and down? And just out of curiosity - why favor Sets instead of lists (haven't worked that much with them)

Comment: Sets will offer much better performance that lists in this scenario. In a list you'd have to traverse the list each time you need to add or remove an item

Comment: For anyone else wanting to achieve the same thing, I got a good idea from Alexlew on Slack - which boils down to adding and removing only modifier keys in the set and ignoring the rest. In most cases it's only three or four keys you'd want to track (ctrl, shift, alt, cmd), and you only need to perform any checking of the set on those specific keys being upped or downed.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/keyboard/latest):

> Longer-term, it makes sense to help track key combinations and a couple other common scenarios. If you have a particular problem you think this library could address more directly, please describe it as a SSCCE in an issue. Please do not suggest the solution. Just describe the scenario. Once it becomes clearer what folks are up to, it will be time to add support for those cases in a coherent way.

So, at least it means that it is not supported right now. I'm not fully sure whether it also means that you should open an issue to encourage this later addition or not.

Now, Chad's answer looks like a good temporary solution to me. It looks even better with swelet's suggestion of tracking only a few modifier keys. Note how if you take this approach you don't need to rely on any `List` or `Set` but you can instead have a little record with 4 booleans.

Finally, if you want for some reasons to track all the keys (if for instance you would like the user being able to link [F1] to some action, then performance-wise it would make sense to use a more efficient representation of sets. Any subset of a finite set for instance can be defined as a single number, each bit being a boolean meaning absence or presence of one particular element. You can do such things with the [Bitwise](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Bitwise) library.

Comment: Thank you for good insight on making things even a little more efficient!